# QtGui QTreeWidgetItem setData holding a float number

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I was wondering if I could keep float values in a QTreeWidgetItem?

When I try to record numbers using setData(0,0,number)  it rounds it up to 6 digits of precision which is not enough for me. I want to keep the exact float value for further calculations.

Comment: You could store it as a string.

Comment: well, I'm trying to keep the precision. strings are not precise enough.

Comment: How? If you convert a Python `float` to a string, it retains all of its precision. You aren't losing anything.

Comment: Please give a simple code example with real values. And also state which version of python you are using.

Comment: @Blender: That is only true up to a certain precision though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of two things, a QVariant can store any type pretty much:

```
v = QtCore.QVariant(aFloat)
aFloat = v.toDouble()[0]
```

And you would store the QVariant as the data.

Or you can set any arbitrary attributes on the item:

```
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
item.foo = 123.123
```

Comment: it's weird! when I do setData(1,QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,QtCore.QVariant(number)) it doesn't display the number anymore while setData(1,QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,number) works...

Comment: Set a string version of it as `Qt.DisplayRole` and the QVariant float accurate version as `Qt.UserRole` so you can treat them separately. Or use my suggestion of just adding it as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Using QVariant with str can do taht I think

```
a = 0.12345678963582

item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole,QtCore.QVariant(str(a)))

.....

val = float(item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString()).strip())
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You are still converting to and from a string regardless of the QVariant

Comment: `assert float(QtCore.QVariant(str(a)).toString()) == a`