# Appending namedtuple data on a QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to append nodes of namedtuple object to a treeView but I'm not sure how to subclass QAbstractItem (if that's even the proper way). I'm still very new to Python so this is confusing to me. Here is my problem code:

```
Exercise = namedtuple('Exercise','name html list')
e_list = []
for i in range(1,6,1):
    dummy_list = [1,2,3,'a','b','c']
    ntup = Exercise("exercise{0}".format(i),'html here',dummy_list)
    e_list.append(ntup)

for e in e_list:
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(e) # gives error
    self.tree_model.appendRow(item) # doesnt execute
```

And here is the the whole program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from collections import namedtuple

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText("Test 1 - doesn't work")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushbutton)

        self.pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton2.setText("Test 2 - works")
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.on_pushbutton2)

        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.clicked[QModelIndex].connect(self.on_clickitem)

        self.tree_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.tree_model)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButton2)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.treeView)

    def on_pushbutton(self):
        Exercise = namedtuple('Exercise','name html list')
        e_list = []
        for i in range(1,3,1):
            dummy_list = [1,2,3,'a','b','c']
            ntup = Exercise("exercise{}".format(i),'html here',dummy_list)
            e_list.append(ntup)

        for e in e_list:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(e) # gives error
            self.tree_model.appendRow(item) # never occurs

    def on_pushbutton2(self):
        txt = 'hello world'
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(txt)
        self.tree_model.appendRow(item)

    def on_clickitem(self,index):
        item = self.tree_model.itemFromIndex(index) # doesn't work
        print "item name:",item.getName() # doesn't work
        print "item html:",item.getHtml() # doesn't work
        print "item list:",item.getList() # doesn't work



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to append the nodes into a tree and when I click on an item I want to get the values of the namedtuple (i.e. the values of 'name', 'html', and 'alist'). Thanks for your help.

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using QTreeWidget and setting the tree item data like this:

```
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
item.mydata = my_namedtuple
```

I found the answer here: [QtGui QTreeWidgetItem setData holding a float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998572/qtgui-qtreewidgetitem-setdata-holding-a-float-number/12012852#12012852)

I didn't know you could just dynamically make an attribute for the tree item.